# Check day of week and time

Tags: php, time

I have been trying to figure out how to get between a day of week and time...I found this snippet of code:

```
function isBetween($from, $till, $input) {
 $f = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i', $from);
 $t = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i', $till);
 $i = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i', $input);
 if ($f > $t) $t->modify('+1 day');
 return ($f <= $i && $i <= $t) || ($f <= $i->modify('+1 day') && $i <= $t);
};
```

and I have managed to get it to check between two times and see if current matches using:

```
if (isBetween('22:30','02:00','23:00')){
 echo "true";
}
```

However I tried doing this

```
if (isBetween('22:30','02:00',date('H:i')){
```

but that just broke the site, I lack experience handling time and I basically want to check between 11pm monday to 2pm tuesday or 11pm monday to 5pm saturday and it has to do this check no matter what day of the year/month meaning I want it to be dynamic not static..

I've also tried:

```
if (date('H') < 14)
```

but it was very simplistic and I didn't know how to get something as complex as both date and hour+seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your missing 1 more closing `)`

```
if (isBetween('22:30','02:00',date('H:i'))){
```

You can just do like this:

```
function isBetween($from, $till, $input) {
 $f = date('H:i', strtotime($from));
 $fd= date('l', strtotime($from));
 $t = date('H:i', strtotime($till));
 $td= date('l', strtotime($till));
 $i = date('H:i', strtotime($input,'+8 hours'));
 $id= date('l', strtotime($input));
 $days = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'); 
 if(array_search($fd,$days)<array_search($id,$days) && array_search($td,$days)>array_search($id,$days)){
    return true;
 }elseif(array_search($fd,$days)==array_search($id,$days) && $f<$i){
    return true;
 }elseif(array_search($td,$days)==array_search($id,$days) && $t<$i){
    return true;
 }
 return false;
};

$from = 'Wednesday 12:00';
$till = 'Saturday 23:00';
$input = 'Friday 12:23';

if(isBetween($from,$till,$input)){
    echo "True";
}else{
    echo "not";
}
```

output = `true`;

Comment: How silly x) that fixed one of my problems, just need to figure out how to get between two dates

Comment: Won't that only check between the two year points? so for day points would I do
'd H:i' instead of 'Y-m-d H:i'?

Comment: sorry, i didnt quite understood the question.  for example.  `Mon 12:00` `Sun 13:00` then check if `Wed 5:00`?

Comment: Yes for example
Monday 12:00 
Sunday 13:00
if Wed 5:00pm falls between those two = true.
Year and month doesn't matter in this case

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this?
$i = date('H:i', strtotime($input . '+8 hours'));
A colon instead of a comma. It's a concatenation, isn't it?