# Conditional based on day of week and time range

Tags: php, if-statement, time, conditional-statements, dayofweek

I'm trying to find a solution to a conditional based on the day of the week and a time range within that day. I've managed to hunt down the code for the day of the week but I can't find how to incorporate a time frame within the day?

For example:

```
IF today is Monday AND between 2pm and 4pm THEN do THIS
```

This is what I have...

```
<?php   
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth'); // PHP supported timezone
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
// get current day:
$currentday = date('l'); ?>
<?php if ($currentday == Monday){ ?>
Monday
<?php } elseif ($currentday == Tuesday){ ?>
Tuesday
<?php } elseif ($currentday == Wednesday){ ?>
Wednesday
<?php } elseif ($currentday == Thursday){ ?>
Thursday
<?php } elseif ($currentday == Friday){ ?>
Friday
<?php } elseif ($currentday == Saturday){ ?>
Saturday
<?php } elseif ($currentday == Sunday){ ?>
Sunday
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm not sure if this may help for the time frame?
[Check day of week and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656789/check-day-of-week-and-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this:

```php
<?php

if (date('l') === 'Monday' && date('G') >= 2 && date('G') < 4) {
    // do something
}
```

You were missing quotes around the day names.

The condition I wrote will evaluate to true on Monday between 2 PM and 4 PM (while 4 PM itself will not, e.g. the last allowed values is 3:59 PM).

Comment: Simple and clean.

Answer (score 0):

you could use different date/time components to streamline the code:

```
function between($value, $start, $end)
{
    return $value > $start && $value <= $end;
}

$hours = date("G");

switch( date("N"))
{
    case 1:  //monday
        if (between($hours,12 + 2,12 + 4 )) //using 24h format to avoid checking am/pm
        {
            // IF today is Monday AND between 2pm and 4pm THEN do THIS
        }
    break;

    case 2: //tuesday
    break;


    //....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better user `date('N')` as it is not language dependant and `date('H')` to take advantage of the 24h format that is better fit for time comparison.

```php
function date_in_frame($test_date, $day, $start, $end){
    $d = new Datetime($test_date);
    return $d->format("N") == $day && $d->format("H") >= $start && $d->format("H") < $end;
}
//test if "now" is Monday between 2pm (14:00) and 4pm (15:59)
var_dump(date_in_frame("now", 0, 14, 16));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code here checks a DateTime is between a start and end time.

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2019-11-18 12:49');

$start = new DateTime('2019-11-18 09:00');
$end = new DateTime('2019-11-18 17:00');

if ($date > $start && $date < $end) {
    echo 'In the zone!';
}
```

Note.

`$date->format('l');` will return Monday or whatever day it is.

`$date->format('H:i');` will return 13:15 or whatever time it is.

Have a play! https://3v4l.org/XK5KR

Comment: I'm looking for day of the week and time, not date.

Comment: You can use `format('H:i')` to get the hour and time, H for the hour, i for the minute. Updated answer. You can still do the comparison using DateTime objects, but use format to get specifics if need be

Answer (score 0):

All the conditions packed into an array is easier for maintenance.

A simplified example:

```
$ranges = [
  ['Monday',12,14, function(){echo "do something";}],
  ['Tuesday',12,14, function(){echo "do something on Tue";}],
  //: more
];

$curWeekDay = date('l');
$hours = date("G");
foreach($ranges as $range){
  if($curWeekDay == $range[0] AND $hours >= $range[1] AND $hours < $range[2]){
    $range[3]();
  }
}
```

Output on Tue 13:25:

```
do something on Tue
```